# COLDFUSION - Finding the sum of rows in a table

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, html-table, sum

I have a table where it outputs all orders placed within a certain date and need to output the total at the end of each row (for the Total VAT + Net Value).

I get the error 'Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values'

What is the simplest way to over come this?

```
<cfquery name="getPrice" dbtype="query">
  select sum(TotalVAT+NetValue) as grandTotal
  from AllOrders
</cfquery>
```

and in my table:

```
 <CFOUTPUT query="AllOrders">
<tr>
<td width="200px">#AllOrders.PurchaseDate#</td>
<td>#AllOrders.Description#</td>
<td>#AllOrders.TotalVAT#</td>
<td>#AllOrders.NetValue#</td>
<td>#getPrice.grandTotal#</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: post your line of code where it happens

Comment: Please include the CF code you're attempting to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getprice.grandtotal` is what you would output.

you are trying to output the entire query.

Comment: Thank you!! It is finally showing an output. However it is displaying the grand total for everything, not just for the row? Is it possible to have it output the total on a row basis?

Comment: then you would include the fields TotalVAT and NetValue then display them in the output for each row

Comment: Sorry I should of included them above, please see the revised edit

Comment: if you want the total for each row just make a new column adding totalvat to netvalue -  <td>#allorders.totalvat+allorders.netvalue#</td>

Comment: Whilst im asking newbie questions.... you dont know how to alter my CF query so it queries it between two dates? The dates are dynamically created so in #StartDate# and #EndDate# format?

Comment: change the sql to select fields from table where date between #start_date# and #end_date#. but i must tell you it makes more sense to use cfstoredproc to avoid sql injection attacks.

Comment: You should open a new question. Be sure to include the data types of your columns +and+ whether they include dates only (12/31/2011) or a date and time (ie 12/31/2011 02:52:30 PM)

Comment: @Chris - Re: *to avoid sql injection attacks* – That is what `<cfqueryparam>` is designed for ;)

Comment: i understand that, but cfquery performance is pretty terrible compared to cfstoredproc.

Comment: Thanks, yes I still need to work on some areas! Can I use multiple 'where' in one CFQUERY?

Comment: you would use "and". select field from table where this = #that# and this1 = #that1#

Comment: so 'AND OrderDate BETWEEN #StartDate# and #EndDate#'?

Comment: if the orderdate is the only conditional it would be where, otherwise it would be " WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN #StartDate# and #EndDate# AND field1 = #field1"

Comment: @Chris - Sorry, but I disagree with such a blanket statement. Using a stored proc is *not* a guarantee of good performance. Many factors can affect performance, but they are usually directly related to the sql statements involved, indexes, whether you are using bind parameters etecetera involved. It is more than just the difference between stored proc and inline query.

Comment: @ChrisBrickhouse Thanks, it seems to be going through but now will not display anything! grr!!!

Comment: all query performance is based on the query itself, and the indexes. but if you really think that procs don't run faster than raw sql then chances are you've never worked with high volumes of data and traffic simultaneously. i have a large, popular music website, and a query that takes 30 seconds minutes to run with cfquery takes less than 2ms to run using cfstoredproc. a compiled query will almost always be faster than raw sql. the execution plan doesn't need to be recreated every single time, and that alone is a huge performance boost. .

Comment: @eq87 - if you're having problems seeing the results of the query just do <cfdump var="#queryname#">

Comment: @Chris - Not sure what "seconds minutes" are. But you misunderstood my response. Making a blanket statement that cfstoreproc is *always* faster than cfquery, because you say one query works faster on your database that way, is wrong. There are no absolutes. But you are certainly entitled to your opinion.

Comment: i never said that every stored procedure call is better, please find where i did. but if you take a query and run it as a stored procedure instead of raw sql, it is almost always faster, and there are mountains of documentation to back it up.

Comment: I am referring to your blanket statement "cfquery performance is pretty terrible compared to cfstoredproc". Honestly, if a single query was taking 30 seconds, it sounds like the sql was not optimized to begin with. There is *usually* a benefit from reusing cached query plans, yes. But these days most databases have caching for dynamic queries too. Especially when you use bind variables. But again, there are no absolutes. Just wrapping something in a stored proc is not a guarantee of good performance. You need to examine the query plans.

Comment: things are fine the way i do them, thanks. i appreciate your attempt to school me though. i've been writing coldfusion code and administering websites since 1997, i know what i'm doing.